# Jinja for loop scope is reset when incrementing variable

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am building a Flask app and am trying to loop through order lines to display the  amount of items in a basket.

```
{% set items = 0 %}
{% for line in current_order.order_lines %} #loops twice in current test
    {% set items = items + line.quantity %} #should add 5 then 2
{% endfor %}

{{ items }} #outputs 0
```

After some research I've found it is a scope issue, i.e. the bottom `{{ items }}` can't see that I have added 5 then 2. How can I increment a value in a Jinja for loop?

Comment: Why are you doing this calculation in the template? You should do it in the view.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is indeed a scoping issue, as [documented in the Jinja2 template reference](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments):

> ### Scoping Behavior
>
> Please keep in mind that it is not possible to set variables inside a block and have them show up outside of it. This also applies to loops.
>
> [...]
>
> As of version 2.10 more complex use cases can be handled using `namespace` objects which allow propagating of changes across scopes[.]

So you could use the [`namespace()` class](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#namespace) as a work-around:

```html
{% set ns = namespace(items=0) %}
{% for line in current_order.order_lines %}
    {% set ns.items = ns.items + line.quantity %}
{% endfor %}

{{ ns.items }}
```

That said, it is *much better* if you calculated the item count *up front* and passed this into the template as part of the `current_order` object or additional context.

Another option is to use the [`sum()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#sum) to sum those quantities:

```html
{% for line in current_order.order_lines %} #loops twice in current test
    <!-- render order line -->
{% endfor %}

{{ current_order.order_lines|sum(attribute='quantity') }}
```